# Application With Audio Calls via VoIP.

Tags: android

Need to develop an application with audio calls via VoIP. The application is only for Android. Any link or tutorials would be very helpful to get me started.

Answer (score 1):

You should spend some time before posting a question here. Refer to this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-31uZDgzCms